# Указатель на объект не передается в другой метод

Tags: ооп, java, graphics

Объявляю переменные bs и g2 как статические .определю их в методе init().запускаю . компилятор выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException (якобы указатель ни на что не указывает ) в методе render(). Если код из  init() запихать в render() ,тогда всё работает правильно . Почему не работает первый вариант (приведенный ниже)??

```
   package mainpack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
//import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int WIDTH = 800; //ширина
    public static int HEIGHT = 300; //высота
    public static String NAME = "Life is game"; //заголовок окна
    public static int x1 = 10;   
   static  Graphics2D g2;
   static  int Y=0;
    static  BufferStrategy bs;
    private boolean running;     
    public int msec  = 0;
    public void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
      //  showStatus("Privet!.");
    }
    public void run() 
    {


        init();

        while(running) {

            render();

        }
    }

    public void init() {



         bs = getBufferStrategy();       
         if (bs == null) {
             createBufferStrategy(2); 
             requestFocus();
             return;
         }

          g2=(Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();  

    }

    public void render() {


        g2.setColor(Color.black); //выбрать цвет
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());  
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, x1, 50);
        g2.drawString(g22.toString(), 0, 70);

        bs.show(); //показать
    }


void kanistra(){

}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Game.NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }



}
```

Comment: возвращает тип буфферизации 1-одиночная (если такая есть) буферизация, 2- двойная буферизация ,3- тройная буферизация ,0 - не задан тип буферизации. это я так понял)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутри `init` вызов `getBufferStrategy()` возвращает `null`, поэтому до кода

```
g2=(Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
```

дело не доходит из-за раннего return'a.

Когда вы во второй раз запускаете код метода `init` в `render`, метод возвращает не `null`, раннего return'а не происходит, и g2 наконец-то получает ненулевое значение.

Думаю, достаточно будет просто убрать `return;` из метода `init`.

Comment: всё заработало ,спасибо) а правильно ли будет сделать иммено так как я сделал , т.е. вызывать методы getBufferStrategy(),bs.getDrawGraphics() один раз при инициализаци ,а не каждый раз при render'е

Comment: @Павлик: Я думаю, один раз в начале должно быть правильнее. Но я не большой специалист по Swing'у. Должно по идее работать. Если не будет -- возвращайтесь, выясним :)